# what's the efficiency of qsqlite data base in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am very new to database and I am trying to implement a offline map viewer. What would be the efficiency of the qsqldatabase? 
To make it extreme, for example, is it possible to download all satellite image of all the detail levels of US from the google's map server and store it in a local sqlite database and still perform real time query based on my current gps location?

Comment: I wonder why you have chosen to use an SQL database for this in the first place.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - because the first thing that comes to mind when you hear "image storage" is an SQL database ;)

Comment: So what should I choose?

Comment: @Nyaruko just store the files normally, but under a scheme that allows you to locate different tiles at different detail levels. Also, I am pretty sure that downloading and using google's satellite imagery is ILLEGAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt Database driver for SQLite uses SQLite internally (surprise!). So the question is more like: Is SQLite the right database to use? My answer: I would not use it to store geographical data, consider to look for a database which is optimized for this task.

If this is not an option; SQLite is really efficient. First check if your data is within the [limits](http://sqlite.org/limits.htmlhttp://sqlite.org/limits.html). Do not forget to create indexes and analyze the database. Then it should be able to handle your task. Here I assume you just want to get an image by its geographical position (but other solutions can be a lot faster because your data is sortable — if I remember correctly SQLite is not optimized for that).

As you will store large blobs, you may want to have a look at the [Internal Versus External BLOBs in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html) document. Maybe this gives you the answer already.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by create indexes and analyze the database? What is the "other solutions?"